# init takes 1 argument but 2 were given? (Positional)

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in python using pygmae. And I am having trouble with Init, it says that It has 2 arguments. but I only gave, one I found other solutions online but those did not quite work, I also got this error multiple times in the past and normally when I would fix it, it would be in very unusual ways such as places where the code is all the way down on the other side of the screen. I get that is how python works, but i'm pretty sure even in the self method I gave, I only gave it one positional argument> Here is the error code if anyone is wondering (I was doing this to make the enemy appear on the screen, so all of that is for the enemy, this problem originated from the fact that I was trying to make the enemy appear on the screen)

```
enemy = Enemy(enemy_image)
```

> TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys

# classes
# Player class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width//2, screen_height//2))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    def create_bullet(self):
        return Bullet(*pygame.mouse.get_pos())
# bullet class
class Bullet (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,10))
        self.image.fill((255,255,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (pos_x,pos_y))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 5
#Making the enemy work
enemy_speed_factor = 1.5
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the enemy and set its starting position"""
        self.screen = screen


        #Load the enemy image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Enemy4.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.scree_rect = screen.get_rect()

        #start each new enemy at the bottom of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.scree_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.scree_rect.bottom

        #store a decimal value for the ships x and y center
        self.centerx = float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.centery = float(self.rect.centery)

        #Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving_up = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the enemys position based on the movement flag"""
        #Upade the enemy's center value, not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.centerx += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.mobing_left and self.rect.left >0:
            self.centerx -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.centery =+ self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.top > self.screen_rect.top:
            self.centery -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        #Update rect object from self.center
        if self.moving_up or self.moving_down:
            self.rect.centery = self.centery
        if self.moving_left or self.moving_right:
            self.rect.centerx = self.centerx
    def blitme(selfself, self):
        """draw the enemy at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

#making the movements for the enemy
def check_keydown_events(events, ship):
    """responds to keypresses"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = True

def check_keyup_evets(event, ship):
    """responds to key releases"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        ship.moving_down = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        ship.moving_up = False


def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    pass


def check_events(ship):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events"""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, enemy)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen"""
    #Redeaw the screen during each pass through the loop
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    enemy.blitme()

    #Make the most recently drawn screeen visible
    pygame.display.flip()


def blitme(self):
    self.screen.blit(self)



# general setup
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# game screen
screen_width = 1920
screen_height = 1080
screen = pygame .display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
background = pygame.image.load("BackGround.png")

# player
player_image = pygame.image.load("Charachter2.png")
player = Player(player_image)
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(player)

# enemy
enemy_image = pygame.image.load("Enemy4.png")
enemy = Enemy(enemy_image)
enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_group.add(enemy)

# Bullet
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

# caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Wild-West Shooter")

# makes game quit
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame:quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet_group.add(player.create_bullet())


    player_group.update()
    bullet_group.update()

    # draw
    screen.blit(background,(0,0)) # background
    player_group.draw(screen) # player
    bullet_group.draw(screen) # bullets
    enemy.draw(screen)
    #thief.draw(screen) # enemy

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)



# makes game run
if __name__ == "__main__" :
        theApp = App()
        theApp.on_execute()
```

Comment: `class Enemy: def __init__(self):` doesn't accept any arguments other than `self`, which is passed automatically

Comment: but for the other classes i gave them more arguments such as pos_x and pos_y

Comment: Right, but this class' constructor doesn't accept any arguments

Comment: Also, please add relevant code only, it is hard to comb through the whole ode for the relevant bits :).

Comment: so the fix for this is to remove self because it is passed automatically?

Comment: No self always needs to be there, as it is implicitly passed. You don't need to mess with the self. You just have to add what ever variables you need to pass to the init method after the self. So, `__init__ (self, what ever else you want)`. If you are familiar with other languages, `self` is basically like `this`.

Comment: I got it now. But after I corrected, I got errors in line 454 and 441, and my code isn't even that long my code is only around 180 @sourvad

Comment: It may be because the error is happening in some library file, not necessarily your code. It would be helpful if you add an update to the question with the traceback of the error.

Comment: @sourvad il make a new question, because it is completely un-related to this (jn a way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `__init__` method for the `Enemy` class takes only 1 argument, which is the `self` argument. Python passes this automatically when an object is created for a class.

For example, if you have a class `Foo`, and its `__init__` method is defined as:

```
def __init__ (self):
    # Do stuff
```

and you create an object as such:

```
bar = Foo()
```

Python automatically converts the object call and adds a `self` argument. Think of it as `self` argument always being there.

Now, if you want to pass two arguments, you need to edit the `__init__` method as such:

```
def __init__(self, image):
    # Do stuff
```

This way, the `__init__` method accepts 2 arguments, the `self` and the `image`. Then you can proceed to create an object as follows:

```
enemy = Enemy(enemy_image)
```

And Python will add the `self` argument to it automatically so that you final object is `enemy = Enemy(self, enemy_image)`